# Active USB-Hub, letting the + and - open?

Tags: usb, hub

I have done some modifications to my Raspberry Pi (Model B). The basic idea is to have an active usb-hub connected to the Raspi, so i can control the power of the hub with a switch(it should all run on battery later).
Basically my question is, whether i can communicate with an usb-device, which is gaining its power from somewhere else, meaning is it possible to connect an usb-device with just D+ and D-
and skip the + and - wires?

Answer (score 1):

You may probably skip connecting +5V, but you most definitely need to connect ground to achieve any communication.

Comment: thx, will try that out